# Adobe Media Encoder 2014.2 Part of audio missing in mp4 AAC rendered files - cache problem?

Tags: audio

Using Encoder 2014.2 for mp4 file encoding in 4 different resolutions

2 different HW systems - Windows 8.1 64, Intel i7, SSD, Nvidia GTX 780x2 SLI

Configured Watched Folders with 4 different presets

Around 20 mp4 moved to watched folder and waited caching to be finished

After encoding first 2-3 files are OK (in all 4 resolutions) but rest have only 1/3 of audio

Cleared cache, moved to other disc - no luck, the same problem - renderd video files missing 2/3 of audio

It might be related to cache.problems?

Fully encoded files have onle one pair of .pek and .cfa files

Partial audio encoded files have 4-8 .pek .cfa files with _1 _2 _3 extension

Tried this one:

1. Launched AME Moved 20 files to watched folder
2. Waited until conforming is done
3. Delete all files ending _1 _2 and _3
4. Start encoding
5. Before each rendering AME still conforming each file, but creating only one new pair of files ending _1
6. Seems problem is gone

Any clues about reason?

Here is the list of initial caching list (size of _1 _2 _3 files are similar to initial file)

•   Directory of C:\Temp_Adobe\Media Cache Files

•   19.02.2015.  09:04       631ÿ242ÿ752 Video_file-035.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ465ÿ860 Video_file-035.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       613ÿ941ÿ248 Video_file-036.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ398ÿ276 Video_file-036.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       613ÿ941ÿ248 Video_file-036.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ398ÿ276 Video_file-036.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:03       631ÿ242ÿ752 Video_file-037.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:03         2ÿ465ÿ860 Video_file-037.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       561ÿ512ÿ448 Video_file-038.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ193ÿ476 Video_file-038.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       561ÿ512ÿ448 Video_file-038.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ193ÿ476 Video_file-038.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       561ÿ512ÿ448 Video_file-038.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ193ÿ476 Video_file-038.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       585ÿ629ÿ696 Video_file-039.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ287ÿ684 Video_file-039.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       585ÿ629ÿ696 Video_file-039.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ287ÿ684 Video_file-039.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:04       585ÿ629ÿ696 Video_file-039.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:04         2ÿ287ÿ684 Video_file-039.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       593ÿ494ÿ016 Video_file-040.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ318ÿ404 Video_file-040.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       593ÿ494ÿ016 Video_file-040.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ318ÿ404 Video_file-040.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       593ÿ494ÿ016 Video_file-040.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ318ÿ404 Video_file-040.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       519ÿ045ÿ120 Video_file-041.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ027ÿ588 Video_file-041.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       519ÿ045ÿ120 Video_file-041.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ027ÿ588 Video_file-041.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       519ÿ045ÿ120 Video_file-041.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ027ÿ588 Video_file-041.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       519ÿ045ÿ120 Video_file-041.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ027ÿ588 Video_file-041.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       602ÿ931ÿ200 Video_file-042.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ355ÿ268 Video_file-042.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       602ÿ931ÿ200 Video_file-042.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ355ÿ268 Video_file-042.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       602ÿ931ÿ200 Video_file-042.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ355ÿ268 Video_file-042.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       602ÿ931ÿ200 Video_file-042.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ355ÿ268 Video_file-042.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       595ÿ066ÿ880 Video_file-043.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ324ÿ548 Video_file-043.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       595ÿ066ÿ880 Video_file-043.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ324ÿ548 Video_file-043.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       595ÿ066ÿ880 Video_file-043.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ324ÿ548 Video_file-043.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       557ÿ842ÿ432 Video_file-044.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ179ÿ140 Video_file-044.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       557ÿ842ÿ432 Video_file-044.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ179ÿ140 Video_file-044.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:05       557ÿ842ÿ432 Video_file-044.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:05         2ÿ179ÿ140 Video_file-044.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       557ÿ842ÿ432 Video_file-044.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ179ÿ140 Video_file-044.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       613ÿ416ÿ960 Video_file-045.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ396ÿ228 Video_file-045.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       613ÿ416ÿ960 Video_file-045.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ396ÿ228 Video_file-045.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       613ÿ416ÿ960 Video_file-045.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ396ÿ228 Video_file-045.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       613ÿ416ÿ960 Video_file-045.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ396ÿ228 Video_file-045.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       619ÿ184ÿ128 Video_file-046.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ418ÿ756 Video_file-046.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       619ÿ184ÿ128 Video_file-046.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ418ÿ756 Video_file-046.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       619ÿ184ÿ128 Video_file-046.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ418ÿ756 Video_file-046.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       619ÿ184ÿ128 Video_file-046.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ418ÿ756 Video_file-046.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       601ÿ358ÿ336 Video_file-047.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ349ÿ124 Video_file-047.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       601ÿ358ÿ336 Video_file-047.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ349ÿ124 Video_file-047.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       601ÿ358ÿ336 Video_file-047.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ349ÿ124 Video_file-047.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:06       601ÿ358ÿ336 Video_file-047.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:06         2ÿ349ÿ124 Video_file-047.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       618ÿ135ÿ552 Video_file-048.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ414ÿ660 Video_file-048.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       618ÿ135ÿ552 Video_file-048.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ414ÿ660 Video_file-048.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       618ÿ135ÿ552 Video_file-048.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ414ÿ660 Video_file-048.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       618ÿ135ÿ552 Video_file-048.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ414ÿ660 Video_file-048.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       619ÿ708ÿ416 Video_file-049.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ420ÿ804 Video_file-049.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       619ÿ708ÿ416 Video_file-049.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ420ÿ804 Video_file-049.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       619ÿ708ÿ416 Video_file-049.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ420ÿ804 Video_file-049.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       619ÿ708ÿ416 Video_file-049.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ420ÿ804 Video_file-049.mp4 48000_3.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       597ÿ164ÿ032 Video_file-050.mp4 48000.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ332ÿ740 Video_file-050.mp4 48000.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       597ÿ164ÿ032 Video_file-050.mp4 48000_1.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ332ÿ740 Video_file-050.mp4 48000_1.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       597ÿ164ÿ032 Video_file-050.mp4 48000_2.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ332ÿ740 Video_file-050.mp4 48000_2.pek
•   19.02.2015.  09:07       597ÿ164ÿ032 Video_file-050.mp4 48000_3.cfa
•   19.02.2015.  09:07         2ÿ332ÿ740 Video_file-050.mp4 48000_3.pek

Answer (score 1):

I would do check on your ram to make sure its not having issues. You can do that with a number of utilities.

If you are running windows there is a built in util called MdSched.exe that will do this for you. Just type it in the search box after hitting the windows key.

You can also boot to a usb or dvd/cd and test it with memtest86. Get it at memtest86.com.

Alex

Comment: I have the same issues on 2 different systems. Motherboards and RAM are different.
One is 8 Gb one bank, other is 16 Gb 4 banks, different vendors.
I will check later with some utility, but its not likely to be cause of problem

Comment: You could improve your answer by expanding a little: maybe a link to one of the utilities.

Comment: Happy with that revision?